# Filtering class properties by a specific criteria

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Consider the following model (.NET 8, C# 12):

```
public partial interface IEntity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public partial interface IEntity<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity, IEntity<TEntity>, new()
{
}

public partial class User: IEntity, IEntity<User>
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public partial class Currency: IEntity, IEntity<Currency>
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public partial class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }

    //// TODO: Fix to get a list of DbSets.
    //public static List<object> GetDbSets () => typeof(ApplicationDbContext)
    //  .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    //  .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite)
    //  .Where(p => p.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: false) != null)
    //  .Where(p => p.GetSetMethod(nonPublic: false) != null)
    //  .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(DbSet<>))
    //  .Cast<object>()
    //  .ToList();

    //// TODO: Fix to get a list of entities.
    //public static List<Type> GetEntities () => typeof(ApplicationDbContext)
    //  .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    //  .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite)
    //  .Where(p => p.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: false) != null)
    //  .Where(p => p.GetSetMethod(nonPublic: false) != null)
    //  .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
    //  .Where(p => p.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith(typeof(DbSet<>).Name))
    //  //.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(DbSet<IEntity>))
    //  .Select(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments() [0])
    //  //.Cast<object>()
    //  .ToList();

    public static List<Type> GetEntityTypesOrderedDelete () => new []
    {
        typeof(User),
        typeof(Account),
        typeof(Transaction),
        typeof(AccountCategory),
        typeof(Currency),
    }
    .ToList();
}

private static void Main ()
{
}
```

I want to get a list of properties `List<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo>` values using the following criteria:

- Properties must be instance, public, and virtual.
- Properties must inherit from `DbSet<IEntity<TEntity>>`.
- The generic `Dbset` properties must have exactly one generic parameter `IEntity<TEntity>`.
- The generic parameter `IEntity<TEntity>` must have exactly one nested generic parameter `TEntity`.
- `TEntity` must adhere to the generic type constraints enforced by `IEntity<TEntity>`.

The first two methods of the `ApplicationDbContext` class do not return anything. As a workaround, I took a hard-coded approach in the third method, which of course is not sustainable for production code.

The ideal solution would have the following signature:

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<PropertyInfo> GetApplicationDbContextDbSets ()
{
    var properties = typeof(ApplicationDbContext)
        .GetProperties();

    return (properties.AsReadOnly());
}
```

I must be missing something or using the APIs incorrectly.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This filtering should fulfill you requirements:

```
public static ReadOnlyCollection<PropertyInfo> GetApplicationDbContextDbSets()
{
    var properties = typeof(ApplicationDbContext)
        // Properties must be instance, public, and virtual.
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Where(x => x.GetGetMethod()?.IsVirtual == true)
        // Properties must inherit from DbSet<IEntity<TEntity>>
        .Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
        .Where(x => x.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DbSet<>)))
        .Where(x => x.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1)
        // The generic Dbset properties must have exactly one generic parameter IEntity<TEntity>
        .Where(x => x.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]
            .GetInterfaces()
            .Where(y => y.IsGenericType)
            .Where(y => y.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IEntity<>)))
            // The generic parameter IEntity<TEntity> must have exactly one nested generic parameter TEntity.
            .Where(y => y.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1)
            // TEntity must adhere to the generic type constraints enforced by IEntity<TEntity>
            .Where(y => y.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0])).Any()
        )
        .ToList();

    return (properties.AsReadOnly());
}
```

In production code I would write this as full for each loop instead of LINQ to have better debuggability and less duplicated expressions.